# FPGA verilog code upload speed and size limit

Tags: fpga, cpu-architecture

I have two question about **FPGA**
1.  I would like to know how large FPGA chip size would be if I create a full CPU with pipeline.
Any calculation method or paper that describes how I can calculate the chip size?
2. If I upload fairly reasonable functions (or modules) to FPGA after compilation, How long would it actually take to write the logic on FPGA? that is, excluding the compilation time and including just uploading time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would depend on the particular CPU, but to give you an idea a Xilinx MicroBlaze Soft Processor Core takes up around 1000 logic cells, maybe up to around 6000 logic cells with peripherals. A high end FPGA like the Xilinx Zynq-7100 has 444K logic cells.

Configuring an FPGA is very quick; the Z-7100 takes about 1-2 minutes to program.

Comment: Quick is subjective - 1 to 2 minutes sounds like a very long time to me ;)